# Distance on the Android Studio

Tags: android, distance

I'm a beginner developer. I have an urban application template. There is a distance in miles. I want to change it in meters or kilometers. Please, help! Here is the code

```
ParseGeoPoint geoPoint = storeObj.getParseGeoPoint(Configs.STORES_LOCATION);

Location poiLocation = new Location("");
poiLocation.setLatitude(geoPoint.getLatitude());
poiLocation.setLongitude(geoPoint.getLongitude());

float distInMeters = currentLocation.distanceTo(poiLocation);
float distInMiles = (float) (distInMeters * 0.000621371);

TextView distTxt = (TextView) cell.findViewById(R.id.sDistanceTxt);
distTxt.setText("  " + String.format("%.2f", distInMiles) + " км ");
```

Comment: You have a variable `distInMeters` already...

Comment: I need to change miles to kilometers

Comment: And you already have it in meters. So kilometers is trivial, as is conversion from miles to kilometers even.

Comment: What do I need to change?